# Why is Angular compiled

Tags: angular, typescript

So javascript is a interpreted language. But angular is a javascript framework but is compiled. Correct me if i am wrong but in angular we compile the typescript code into javascript code and then interpret. Why do we compile angular?

Comment: Because a browser cannot run the typescript code and hence it needs to be compiled as vanilla JS. FYI, browsers do compile your JS.

Comment: is your question about Angular compiler or TypeScript compiler?

Comment: @Mr.Alien Isn't javascript interpreted?

Comment: @Maximus its little bit about both i dont know what happens after i serve the angular file

Comment: that's a too broad question, can you make it more specific?

Comment: @mayanksingh https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138521/is-javascript-interpreted-by-design

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular builds on Typescript, not Javascript. Since Typescript is just a language Extension [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript) Browsers can't interpret it.

The Compiler (or more exact Transpiler) transpiles the Angular-Typescipt code to Javascript-Code that the browser can interpret.

Comment: This didn't quite answer the question OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

Converting from TypeScript to JavaScript is called compiling here.
Compiling doesn't mean binary code is created in this case.
For this kind of translation, also the term transpilation is used instead of compilation.

The compile step in Angular also generates JavaScript code for Angular specific view binding syntax `like`(click)="myClickHandler($event)`or`[(ngModel)]="someValue"` and also for component and directive instantiation.
This is called AoT compilation, but is not related to TypeScript-to-JavaScript compilation, but instead relates to the component compilation step that also existed in AngularJS 1.x.

In Angular 2/4 with AoT the Angular component templates are parsed at compile time and replaced by generated TypeScript code (which is then transpiled to JavaScript).
This way the browser doesn't have to parse the component templates and create bindings, after loading the Angular application, but instead just needs to run the already included code.

There is also a `DynamicModule` that allows to do this at runtime for use cases where components are created at runtime from data that only is available at runtime (like CMS systems)